# Tippecanoe avoid clipping for UK polygon dataset

Tags: mapbox, tippecanoe

I am trying to create a tileset with polygon for the whole UK and I want them to display a label from the centroid of each polygon.

I want all the labels and polygons visible at all zoom levels.

I have tried with this tippecanoe:

```
tippecanoe -f -o test.mbtiles -b0 -r0 -pf --read-parallel -L'{"file":"./polygons_uk.geojson", "layer":"polygons_uk", "description":"polygons"}' -L'{"file":"./polygons_centroid2.geojson", "layer":"polygons_centroid", "description":"polygon centroid"}'
```

and with other options like: -b2 -r1 -z22 -Z2 --no-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit and also with --not-clipping (this option doesn't work because it automatically throw the error Large unclipped (-pc) feature may be duplicated across)

Is there anyway to create the mbtiles with different Tippecanoe? so for example polygons form one side and centroids for other and then join in one tileset?

any idea how to tweak this tippecanoe to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of tries and errors... I have found a way to manage what I wanted> I am leaving here the answer so anyone with same issue can work on it.

First I have generate different mbtiles one for polygons and other for labels both of them should be at the same max zoom level, also is good idea to eliminate/exclude all the fields you wont need, so with:

```
tippecanoe -f -o polygon.mbtiles -z14 -Z2 --read-parallel -L'{"file":"./polygon.geojson", "layer":"polygon", "description":"polygon"}' -L'{"file":"./polygon_centroid.geojson", "layer":"polygon_centroid", "description":"polygon Centroids"}'



tippecanoe -f -o labels.mbtiles -b2 -r1 -pf -z14 -Z2 -pf --read-parallel -L'{"file":"./labels.geojson", "layer":"labels", "description":"Labels"}'
```

So with these two mbtiles generated I could join them in one tileset by using:

```
tile-join -o polygon_labels.mbtiles *.mbtiles
```